# Pulling data from database and making it JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to pull some data from database and make `data['datetime']` JSON serializable to pass it from Django to Highcharts. I thought my method would work, but it appears it does not. The error I'm getting at the moment is `Type not serializable` since it's not passing the condition from function json_serial. What am I doing wrong, until now I thought that dict['key'] would pass such logic parameter?

```
from .models import Heater
import json
from datetime import datetime

def json_serial(obj):
"""JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial
    raise TypeError ("Type not serializable")

class ChartData(object):    
    def check_heater_data(self):
        data = {'datetime': [], 'temp_max': [],
                 'temp_min': []}

        valves = Heater.objects.all()

        for unit in valves:
            data['temp_max'].append(unit.temp_max)
            data['temp_min'].append(unit.temp_min)
            data['datetime'] = json_serial(data['datetime'].append(unit.datetime))

        jsonstring = json.dumps(data)
        jsondata = json.loads(jsonstring)

        return jsondata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing `list` object to `json_serial` function.

Here: `json_serial(data['datetime'].append(unit.datetime))`, which is obviously not an instance of `datetime`.

Try to change it to something like this: `data['datetime'].append(json_serial(unit.datetime))`.